# jquery mobile 1.4.2 footer navbar flicker issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I recently upgraded to from jquery mobile 1.3 to 1.4.2. The issue I have is when i click on a radio button in the page, the persistent navbar in the footer flickers (disappers, and immediately appears again). I searched everywhere but could not find a solution. I tried adding `data-tap-toggle="false"` and also `data-position="fixed"` to the footer, but no luck. Can someone help me resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this flicker issue by adding `style="position: fixed !important;"` to the footer div. Hope this helps someone facing a similar issue.